# Format from date string

Tags: php

I have this string "0001-01-01T00:00:00.0000000+01:00".

I try to create a validation rule like `Y-m-d\TH:i:s.uP` but this fails.
Which is the correct format for this string?

```
public function rules()
{
    return [
        [
            ['requested_delivery_date'],'datetime', 'format' => 'php: Y-m-d\TH:i:s.uP'
        ],
    ];
}
```

Comment: You have to specify [which format](https://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.formats.php) you want to use, or which class or function you plan to use.

Comment: Actually i am trying to find the format it is already in use and create the validation rule. The data come from external software and i do not know the format there.

Comment: I don't think you understand. There are various formats to parse dates. They are not all the same. Let me ask the question another way: Could you show us the PHP you plan to use with the validation rule? It doesn't matter that it currently fails. Please add that code to the question, don't put it in a comment.

Comment: https://www.php.net/manual/en/datetimeimmutable.createfromformat.php: _"`u`-  Fraction in microseconds (**up to six digits**)"_ - that's why your pattern fails with the given value, because you got _seven_ digits there.

Comment: @CBroe wanna bet that that's a typo? But well spotted!

Comment: update the problem. the code is in a Yii Model.
The model fails because of the validation rule. But i donot know what is the correct one. The 'u' as mentioned is up to six digits, while i receive 7.

Comment: From what I can read in [the YII documentation](https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/2.0/en/output-formatting#date-and-time) it uses the [ICU format](https://unicode-org.github.io/icu/userguide/format_parse/datetime/).

Comment: _"But i donot know what is the correct one. The 'u' as mentioned is up to six digits, while i receive 7."_ - you can not use this to parse just _any_ arbitrary date format, but only those you can assemble out of the _given_ format specifiers. You _could_ put a `?`after the `u`, that allows for _any_ arbitrary "byte" ... But then any input value like `[...]0000X+01:00` would also pass. If you can't have that - then you will probably find an altogether _different_ way to validate this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is fixed by adding a Behavior. So in the model I have something like that

```
public function behaviors()
{
    return [
       
        [
            'class' => DateTimeFormatBehavior::class,
            'attributeTypes' => [
                'requested_delivery_date' => DateTimeInterface::ATOM,
                   ....
            ],
        ],
    ];
}
```

and in the Behavior I do the conversion like that:

```
$this->owner->{$attribute} = (new DateTime($value))->format(DateTimeInterface::ATOM);
```

The file bellow is the Behavior:

```
    class DateTimeFormatBehavior extends Behavior
    {

    public $owner;
    public array $attributeTypes = [];
    public string $toDateTimeFormat = DateTimeInterface::ATOM;

    public function applyFormat(Event $event): void
    {
        $attributeTypes = $this->attributeTypes;
        foreach ($attributeTypes as $attribute => $toDateTimeFormat) {
            if (isset($this->owner->{$attribute})) {
                $value = $this->owner->{$attribute};
                if ($value != null) {
                    $this->owner->{$attribute} = (new DateTime($value))->format($toDateTimeFormat);
                }
            }
        }
    }

    public function events(): array
    {
        $handlers = [];

        $toAppliedFormat = 'toAppliedFormat';
        $handlers[BaseActiveRecord::EVENT_BEFORE_INSERT] = $toAppliedFormat;
        $handlers[BaseActiveRecord::EVENT_BEFORE_VALIDATE] = $toAppliedFormat;
        $handlers[BaseActiveRecord::EVENT_BEFORE_UPDATE] = $toAppliedFormat;

        return $handlers;
    }

    public function toAppliedFormat(Event $event): void
    {
        $this->applyFormat($event);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The possible date format as per your provided time string `0001-01-01T00:00:00.0000000+01:00`

- **"0001-01-01"** is in date format  `YYYY-MM-DD`
- **T** could be the separator between date and time
- 00:00:00.0000000 indicates time in format HH:II:SS:sssssss
- +01:00 could be timezone

I am not sure that regex can validate it properly. So, It will be good if you use a custom function to validate this type of date format.
Or validate date, time and timezone in separate variables and append them as per your format while saving  in db.